# What is the best method of making these intricate div-based social media boards responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've designed a couple of div-based boards (resembling the 'moodboards' that are typically done up in PS or another graphics program for social media; ultimately, each of the child divs will have an image background), and I'm happy with how they look, but I'd like to make them responsive.

This is an example of one of the boards:

```html
<div style="width: 500px; max-width: 100%; background: white; height: 500px; position: relative; overflow:hidden; border: 4px solid white;">

    <div style="position: absolute; width: 250px; height: 250px; -webkit-clip-path:polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0%, 100% 0); clip-path:polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0%, 100% 0); -moz-clip-path:polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0%, 100% 0); background: darkred;"></div>
    <div style="bottom: 0; right: 0px; position: absolute; width: 250px; height: 250px; -webkit-clip-path:polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0%, 100% 0); clip-path:polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0%, 100% 0); -moz-clip-path:polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 0%, 100% 0); background: #222; transform: rotate(180deg); overflow: hidden;">
        <div style="width: 250px; height: 315px; -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); transform: rotate(180deg); background: red; background-position: center; margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;">...</div>
 </div>
    <div style=" position: absolute; background: #230000; height: 150px; width: 150px; border-radius: 100%; z-index: 99999999999; left: 34%; bottom: 34%; border: 4px solid white;">...</div>
    <div style="bottom: -58px; left: -58px; position: absolute; background: #222; height: 355px; width: 355px; transform: rotate(45deg); border: white solid 4px; overflow:hidden;">
        <div style="width: 400px; height: 375px; -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); transform: rotate(-45deg); background: #550000; background-position: center; margin: -106px 0px 0px -15px;">...</div>
 </div>
    <div style="top: -58px; right: -58px; position: absolute; background: violet; height: 355px; width: 355px; transform: rotate(45deg); border: white solid 4px; overflow: hidden">
        <div style="background: black; width: 400px; height: 375px; -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); transform: rotate(-45deg); background: #070000; background-position: center; margin: 75px 0px 0px -15px;">...</div>
</div>

</div>
```

The max-width on this particular one is 500px, which I think would be the 'baseline', but I'd like to have it look at least decent if scaled down to a width of 300px or so.  You'll also note that all the styling is done inline; this is because the place where they'll be used only allows inline CSS styling.  Hence, media-queries are (unfortunately) unavailable.

Because they're rather intricate, I don't want to lose the basic form -- or, at least, I'd like to minimize the deformation -- so which method would be best for this? Am I stuck trying to finagle the same look with percentages?

Comment: This is will be quite troublesome

Comment: Have you considered using an SVG to generate such a convoluted shape?

Comment: Hmm... I have not, actually.  Didn't even cross my mind!  I'll look into it.  Thank you!